# AFK command `on_message()` mentions check not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to make a basic AFK command but when I check if a user is in the server AFK list and it has been mentioned and I try to send the afk message it doesn't work! It doesn't even show any error.

Here is my code:

```py
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-", intents=intents, case_insensitive=True)

afk_lists = {}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user.name}")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    global afk_lists

    if message.mentions:
        for user in message.mentions:
            if user.id in afk_lists:
                await message.channel.send(f"{user.mention} is currently AFK!")

    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command()
async def afk(ctx):
    global afk_lists

    server_id = ctx.guild.id
    if server_id not in afk_lists:
        afk_lists[server_id] = []
    user_id = ctx.author.id
    afk_lists[server_id].append(user_id)
    await ctx.send("AFK set!")

@bot.command()
async def show_afk_list(ctx):
    global afk_lists

    server_id = ctx.guild.id
    if server_id in afk_lists:
        afk_list = afk_lists[server_id]
        await ctx.send(f"AFK List: {afk_list}")
    else:
        await ctx.send("AFK List is empty!")

token = "MY_TOKEN"
bot.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below you write the user ids in this pattern
afk_list[server_id] with the user id in it

but in the check

```py
if user.id in afk_lists:
    await message.channel.send(f"{user.mention} is currently AFK!")
```

where you check if the user id is in the list

you need to check if the user id is in the server afk list

like this

```py
if user.id in afk_lists[message.guild.id]:
    ...
```

where you should add a check if the message is even sent on a guild to reduce error messages ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working now, But I have another question it keeps sending the `{user.mention} is currently AFK!` how can I solve it? If it put it outside of the for loop it wont work